# can some one help to show the next div using the same calss

Tags: jquery, html

```
<span class="s1">show me</span>
<div class="show">hello world</div>
<span class="s1">show me</span>
<div class="show">hello world</div>
```

i tried this but not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".s1").click(function () {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

if click the s1 thei need to show the next div

Comment: can you explain with code samples?

Comment: `.t5` where is it? and you post a invalid html.

Comment: add a proper code first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to add a target selector at your `<span>`
you can check DEMO [here](http://jsfiddle.net/te2Rj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".s1").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried next but its also not working..

Comment: Please post your correct HTML markup. Currently I cannot see your `.t5`

Comment: Based on your edit, you need to use `$(".s1").click` instead of `$(".t5").click`

Comment: You need to make sure that you've included jQuery properly and put above code after you've added jQuery

Answer (score 0):

where is `.t5` in your question?

and use `$(function(){});` instead of `$(document).ready(function($){});` just simpler...

```
$(function(){
 $(".t5").click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`next()` can be used if you are  using **same selector**.

Since, you are saying same class..`next()` can be used in tyour scenario.

***Gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector**.*

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".t5").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**Hope this helps..**

Answer (score 0):

Felix is Right. But if you want to find a specific element then try this

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".s1").click(function() {
        var nextDiv = $(this).nextAll(".show").get(0);
        $(nextDiv).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
    });
});
```

See it working here 
http://codepen.io/sajjad26/pen/jLagb

Comment: i tried this but not working..

Comment: Yes you are right, next only test the very next element not all the next siblings. I have edited the code and provided a link where its working. let me know if it helps.